# Getting little boxes instead of actual characters

Tags: java

I am reading a stream using `inputStream`. The code is below

```
buffer = new byte[8];
try {
    while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
        int numBytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
        System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, numBytes));
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But instead of getting characters i am getting somewhat like below

[image]

What are these and how can get actual characters.

Comment: Go read about UTF-8 and UniCode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply the appropriate character set argument to the `String` constructor. (That's the 4th argument - missing in your code - and has the wrong default for your data.)

Otherwise the `String` will misinterpret your data.

You may well find that

`java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8")`

is the one you need.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading bytes and naively translating into strings. That works in a simple scenario, but bytes make up characters in different combinations. This is called *character encoding*, and I suspect you're running into issues wrt. this.

At a minimum, you need to determine the original encoding of the file you're reading, and provide this encoding as a constructor argument to the `String`. This will tell String how to translate an array of bytes to an array of characters (and hence a string)

See [this document](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for more info on encodings.